# Rails 3 application is throwing an error when "Accept: none" HTTP headers are passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-headers, mime-types

We've been seeing Airbrake exceptions when certain browsers request our website but specify an `Accept: None` HTTP header (mostly mobile, it looks like). After a bunch of research, it seems like most consumer-facing applications just ignore Accept HTTP headers and send HTML, and we previously fixed this by adding this to our `mime_types.rb` file

```
Mime::Type.register "none", :html
```

but then our emails started being sent in plain-text, I believe because we're redefining how `text/html` is supposed to work. Is there a better fix so that we still send HTML when someone sends an `Accept: None` header?

edit: I forgot to say, this is what I got when I ran `rails c`, and I'm wondering if I'm perhaps re-defining HTML.

```
$ rails c
/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant HTML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another fix would be to add the following `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController`

```
def fix_accept_headers_for_none
  if request.formats.include?("none")
    request.format = :html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Mime::Type.register "text/html", :html, %w(none)
```

which adds `"none"` as a `mime_type_synonym` for `html`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html#method-c-register

Comment: This actually creates a warning because it redefines the `HTML`  constant in `MimeType`